# Halt chain to get balance of new wallet on Ropsten?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, ropsten

I am running through the voting dapp tutorial (https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-2-30b3d335aa1f) and am attempting to deploy to the Ropsten testnet. When I call

> web3.eth.getBalance('0xee865de6ebbbe517d079cf5effb274670284963e')

while running the chain on geth, I get this error

> Error: missing trie node 32004e17802c4fae5def997f9e5b641b4b8f25a4ca7c50d98e597cb7ece65e4a (path )
>       at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
>       at RequestManager.send (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:61:22)
>       at Eth.send [as getBalance] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:145:58)
>       at evalmachine.:1:-52
>       at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:53:29)
>       at Object.runInContext (vm.js:108:6)
>       at TruffleInterpreter.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/lib/repl.js:136:17)
>       at bound (domain.js:301:14)
>       at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
>       at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:433:10)

And if I halt geth and the chain, I get back the correct response.

> { [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }

Does anyone understand why this is, and perhaps answer if I need to have the chain up to date and running on my machine in order to interact with it?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

When working with public networks, make sure you're fully synced to them before using them, that should solve the issue.